# error display in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a piece of code below which is part of my class. It limits the user to entering numbers within a particular range. I just wanted to know how to add in like maybe a error message on my GUI or onto the console saying "Please try again" if user has entered numbers outside the given range.

```
        try { 
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                String A = textField.getText(); 
                String B = textField_1.getText(); 
                int myInt_2 = Integer.parseInt(B);
                int myInt = Integer.parseInt(A);
                if((myInt >= 0 && myInt <= 100) && ( myInt_2 >= 0 && myInt_2 <= 100)) { 
                    bufferedWriter.write(textField_2.getText()); 
                    bufferedWriter.write(",");
                    bufferedWriter.write(textField.getText()); 
                    bufferedWriter.write(',');
                    bufferedWriter.write(textField_1.getText());
                    bufferedWriter.write(',');
                    bufferedWriter.write(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    bufferedWriter.write(',');
                    bufferedWriter.write(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                     // Always close files.
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                }

        }catch (IOException ex) { 
            System.out.println("Error writing file" + fileName + "'" );
```

Comment: Use a JOptionPane for a modal error dialog.

Comment: [Similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java&oq=s&aqs=chrome.1.69i60j69i59j69i60l4.1589j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+display+error+message) can be easily found via Googling this site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have tried this JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, ex);

Comment: do i add another catch statement and put it below that ? because it wasn't working for me

Comment: Ross: In this situation I wouldn't do `e.toString()` as the end user would have absolutely no idea what to make of that. Translate the error yourself into understandable words and insert **that** into the JOptionPane.

Comment: e.g., `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(realGuiComponent, "File " + fileName + " was not found", "File Not Found Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);`, or some such. Code not tested.

Comment: Or on user entry error, I'd try to be as informative to the user as possible, then I often clear the offending component, such as a JTextField, and set the focus on it so the user can correct it. Even better is to create a data entry GUI that is as idiot proof as possible, by disabling buttons when complete data has not yet been entered, and only enabling them afterwards, and by using components that limit input to valid input such as formatted text fields or JSpinners...

Comment: that seems to advanced for me :P I just want an error to pop up when the user enters incorrect values notifing them to try again and change their values. But I might try that once I get the idea of enabling my error first :)

Comment: it's just I've trying putting some errors but none of them are popping up at the moment

Comment: Then you know the drill, you've been here long enough: you create and post a valid [mcve].

Comment: And again, re `"if user has entered numbers outside the given range"` -- use a JSpinner or JList or JComboBox that forces the user to only enter values within the range.